# How can I go back to showing the content of /index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's part of my `.htaccess` file:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)$ /article/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

But the problem is that when `title` is empty it doesn't show me the content of `http://www.domain.com/index.php`. I can't even link to `http://www.domain.com/` anymore without throwing the error.

**PHP: http://www.domain.com/article/index.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['title']))
{
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `title` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title'])."'");
}
else
{
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'");
}

$b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a) or mysql_error();

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're never passing in `$_GET['id']` for your `else` case.

Comment: Well, I assumed if `title` is empty I'd just grab the `$_GET['id']` and pass it into the query. And if there's no record with that `id`, I'd just throw an error. Or is that a mistake?

Comment: but your htaccess rule does not supply an `id` param so it is always empty.

Comment: does it need to? because I just thought the only time `id` wouldn't be empty is if someone wanted to link to an article directly, i.e. /article/?id=1, or maybe I'm just misunderstanding what you're trying to tell me :/

Comment: I mean it's fine when I link to `/randomtitle` or `/article/?id=3`, the only problem I'm having is that when someone types in `http://domain.com/` it throws the mysql error in `article/index.php`, but I'd just want it to show the `/index.php` page instead.

Comment: @krysis Yor current rewrite rule will discard any existing query string (e.g. `id=123` etc). To add old query string to the new one, add `QSA` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have 2 choices:

1. Use this rule: If home page is hit, then `title` parameter will be empty (so you have to handle this moment somehow -- adjust your PHP code accordingly).

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z_-]*)$ /article/index.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

2. Use specific rule for home page/website root hit (add it **before** your current rule):

```
RewriteRule ^$ /article/index.php?title=home [QSA,L]
```

The `title=home` means it's a hit for website root (you can change `home` to whatever you want).